# complexity of solving $n \times n$ rank deficient linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, computational-complexity

I think it is known that given a nonsingular $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, solving a linear system $Ax =b$ for $x$ can be done in $O(n^3)$ steps.

Now assume $A$ is of rank $r <n$ and suppose one is looking for *any* solution $x$ of $Ax=b$. How many steps does this take? A result that depends on $r,n$ or where $r$ is a function of $n$ would be most useful for me. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Gaussian elimination, you get equivalent upper triangular system in $\mathcal{O}(n^2r)$ steps. Then, it takes another $O(n)$ steps to solve that system, therefore the answer is $\mathcal{O}(n^2r)$. I don't know if there are any special methods it the case $r$ and $n$ satisfie some additional conditions such as $r \ll n$  ...

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me a reference for this?

Comment: First of all, Gaussian elimination is just a fancy term for manipulating linear equations and you have done it if you have solved a $3\times 3$ or bigger system of equations. When you were solving the system, you might have **multiplied a equation by some number** and you might have **subtracted one equation from another** from time to time. This is Gaussian elimination:) Though, when one does the elimination, he often writes equations in more compact way. Take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html) or you just google it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. I know what is Gaussian elimination. But how does one show that it takes no more than O(n^2r) steps? I have been googling all day and also looking at books in Matrix analysis/computation, but I couldn't find a precise statement that I can cite.